# Angular 14 upgrade - ERROR ReferenceError: process is not defined

Tags: angular, angular14upgrade

After upgrading app from angular 13 to angular 14, the code is compiling successfuly bt I get below error and the app is not loading.
I tried with below link
https://github.com/twilio/twilio-client.js/issues/284

But no luck. Please help me out.

````
errorCollection.js:60 ERROR ReferenceError: process is not defined
    at 6788 (main.js:1:737684)
    at __webpack_require__ (main.js:1:981298)
    at main.js:1:2104500
    at main.js:1:2796598
    at Object.<anonymous> (main.js:1:2796622)
    at Object.execute (amd.min.js:1:599)
    at declaration.execute (named-exports.js:40:19)
    at i (system.min.js:4:3448)
    at t (system.min.js:4:3417)
    at system.min.js:4:3679```
````